# Laravel Nova: BelongsToMany. Displaying list on details page based on a condition (from db)

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I am developing a Web application using Laravel Nova. Nova is quite a new CMS system for Laravel. What I am now having trouble with many to many relationship and presenting data.

I have a users table with the following data

```
users - id, name, email, role
```

Then I have a departments table with the following data.

```
departments - id, name, code
```

They have many-to-many relationship with a pivot table like this.

```
departments_users - id, department_id, users_id
```

In the User resource if I added this in the fields method

```
public function fields(Request $request)
    {
        return [
            ID::make()->sortable(),

            //other fields
            BelongsToMany::make("Departments")
        ];
    }
```

Because of I added BelongsToMany in the User resource, if I go to the user details page, I will see something like this.

[image]

Basically what I mean is the option to display list of departments of users and option to attach departments to user. But I do not want to display that option/list all the time. I only want to display it based on the role. I mean something like this in the fields method. Please, read the comment in the following code.

```
public function fields(Request $request)
    {
        return [
            ID::make()->sortable(),
            //other fields
            BelongsToMany::make("departments")//Do this only if the user role is "staff"
        ];
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simple to achieve using laravel nova authorization.

You can add `->canSee()` to `BelongsToMany` field.

You didn't specified which user has to have role "stuff". Logged in or edited.

If logged then just make:

```
BelongsToMany::make("departments")
    ->canSee(function ($request) {
        return $request->user()->role == 'stuff';
    }),
```

If edited user:

```
BelongsToMany::make("departments")
    ->canSee(function ($request) {
        return $this->role == 'stuff';
    }),
```

For more info check [Field Authorization docs](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/1.0/resources/authorization.html#fields)

Comment: Is there a way to retrieve the id of details page from URL as well?

Comment: if you mean ID of the current detailed resource. It's $this->id

Comment: Thanks so much. That is exactly what I wanted.